# Reading plain text response in WSO2

Tags: wso2

I am a new bee to WSO2. I am using wso2esb-4.7.0. What I am trying to do is this
(a) Call a rest servrice. The input to the rest service is XML. I have created a proxy and I am passing the input XML using the tryIT UI
(2) A sample response from the rest service is [1234], from which I need to extract the string 1234 and assign to a variable for further processing.
My TCP monitor shows that the right response is coming from the backend rest service. I have tried various options for reading the response and extracting the string, but not with any luck.

Also, the tryIt UI shows the response as SomeJunkValue
Now the definitions

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="testUpdateSubstanceProxy"
       transports="http"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target inSequence="callUpdateSubstanceURISequnec">
      <outSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>

<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="callUpdateSubstanceURISequnec" onError="fault" trace="enable">
   <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
   <send receive="gov:/receiveSubstanceIdSequnce">
      <endpoint key="gov:/CallUpdateURISubstanceAddressPoint"/>
   </send>
</sequence>

<sequence name="receiveSubstanceIdSequnce" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <send/>
  <!--  A sample response is [1234]. How do I extract 1234 from the response and assign it to a variable-->   
</sequence>

<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <address uri="http://localhost:7014/ourURL" format="pox">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: does backend service send the response in json way?

Comment: Yes. The response would be like [x,y]Well I ended up writing class mediator to handle this. Wondering whether there is something better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing class mediator to handle this. Wondering whether there is something better

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
  <property xmlns:m0="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"
                      name="payload"
                      expression="$body/m0:text"/>
```

This will read the text content to a property called `payload`